# UITableView in a UIScrollView - How to make the view scroll, but not the TableView in itself?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Imagine, there is a UIViewController with a UIScrollView in it. At the top of the view there is an UIImageView, some UILabels and other things. Furthermore, there is a UITableView which content is Dynamic Prototypes. I attach a picture to make it clear:

[image]

I haven't got a static amount of cells in the UITableView so it could be scrollable. My problem is the following: the UITableView scrolls in itself but I want to scroll the whole View. What is the best possibility to do that?

---

Possible solutions I've founded today

1) The first thing is: I create a UITableViewController and declare a header section in which I include all my labels, images etc. programmatically (I would love to use the interface builder for that...)

2) Another solution is to calculate the height of the view. I tried the best to do it like this way - but: without success. If this is the best way to do that: Can anybody give an example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would ditch the `UIScrollView` and just use a `UITableView`. You can add a `UIView` object as the `tableHeaderView` of the `UITableView` just by dragging it in in Interface Builder. Now since everything is part of the `UITableView` hierarchy, everything will scroll together as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day - it's like a preferred christmas present ;o)

Comment: /touches finger to nose and rockets up SO's chimney

Answer (score 2):

You could also try setting `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` on your `scrollView`.  Depending on your setup, this may make the scroll view respond to the touch first instead of the table view.

From Apples [`UIScrollView` Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/UIScrollView_Class.pdf#page12):

> `delaysContentTouches`
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether the scroll view delays the
>   handling of touch-down gestures.
>
> `@property(nonatomic) BOOL delaysContentTouches`
>
> Discussion
>
> If the value of this property is `YES`, the scroll view delays handling
>   the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the
>   intent. If the value is `NO` , the scroll view immediately calls
>   `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:`. The default
>   value is `YES`.

Comment: I'll try this, too - seems to be another great solution. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to (as you've mentioned) add the `UIView` containing the image and buttons to the actual `UITableView`. Embedding it in the scroll view will produce the undesired behavior that you're seeing.

I would recommend returning the `UIView` as the header view for the first section of your table view. You can do this by implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

If you maintain an `IBOutlet` to the view containing your image/labels, you can return it here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I do it like this way, I have to implement all the images/labels programmatically, right? I want to avoid that...

Comment: Nope, you can still use Interface Builder, as long as the `UIView` containing your images/labels is defined as an `IBOutlet` on the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: ah okay! Now I understand what you mean. Your're right! A great solution, thank you for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is same demo i hope its helps you from iphone sorce code library

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html
thank you