# Scroll a view except a part of it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want a screen with scroll, and I want to scroll until a part of the view. When I reach this, this part will be fixed on the top and you can go on scrolling. In the image:

[image]

You begin scrolling until the buttons part, then, the buttons stay fixed in the top and you can scroll more. It's like the spotify app effect in the lists, more or less, if you know it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your image offers no more explanation to this question, it is a grey background and a button. It sounds like what you are trying to achieve is the same affect as a tableView with section headers. I'd start with googling that in order to be able to use some correct terminology

Comment: the image represents the screen, I put the buttons section in order to explain what I want. It's hard to explain it

Comment: Again, from someone who doesn't know what you are trying to do. I see no example of anything, I see a button on a grey background with no examples or samples of any kind. I understand what you are trying to do, you want a view to stick to the top of the view when its Y value hits the top and it to move when the next one comes along e.g. what the tableview section headers do, like the contacts app with the header for each letter 'A', 'B', 'C' etc

Comment: Agree that it's not super clear, but I get the question.  The answer is that this is out of the box behavior for UITableView headers.  Rolling your own would be very challenging.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332891/uitableview-in-a-uiscrollview-how-to-make-the-view-scroll-but-not-the-tablevi

Comment: I dont want to stick in the top the first part, just the buttons sections. I mean, you scroll and everythings move until you reach the buttons section, then, the buttons stick in the top and you can scroll. It's almost like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7npk4lrzmag0sn/IMG_9331.MOV but when you reach the shuffle button, the button sticks in the top and you scroll normally

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this by implementing the [`-scrollViewDidScroll:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#jumpTo_7) method in your scroll view's delegate. When the view scrolls, check the offset to see if the button is visible. If it is, and if it's close to the correct position, you could remove it from the scroll view and position it above the scroll view in the position you want.